# HTML5 required tag not working with my javascript created functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making my input fields in javascript / jquery, but I would like to use the required tag on it. However it doesn't seem to work since it keeps on submitting, not only does it submit, it doesn't even pop up a message related to not filling out the input field. I use bootstrap aswell in case this could be a game changer.

my HTML5 code: (yes, I have declared it as as html5 document)
ignore the buttons IN the form, those aren't related to the problem. I just placed the form tags to ensure you would understand I do have a form wrapped around it... and maybe the problem could be because of the button.

```
<form  id='my_form' class="container-fluid" action="" method="POST">
 <button id='resetInputs' type='button' onclick='getResetInputs()' class='btn btn-danger fa fa-refresh fa-2x resetInputs'></button>
 <button type='button' id='saveBtn' class='btn btn-info fa fa-download fa-2x saveBtn' required name="submit" onclick="saveExerciseAjaxCall()"></button>
</form>
```

The javascript/jquery function I would like to use it on:

```
function getExerciseTitle() {
 var exerciseTitle = $('<input/>', {
 'class': 'getExerciseTitle form-group form-control required',
 'type': 'text',
 'name': 'getExerciseTitle',
 'id': 'getExerciseTitle',
 'placeholder': 'Exercise title',
 'required': true,
 'oninvalid': "this.setCustomValidity('I would like to have a title!')",
 'oninput': "this.setCustomValidity('')"
 });
  return exerciseTitle;
 }
```

the function gets appended to:

```
$('form').append(getExerciseTitle());
```

So, what am I missing out right now?

Cheers!

Comment: add a preventDefault() at the onclick or inside the SaveExerciceAjaxCall()?

Comment: You can ignore the buttons in the form tag itself. Those aren't related. but it seemed a bit silly to just place 2 form tags and that's it.

Comment: What browser are you using this with?

Comment: Google chrome..

Comment: `but it seemed a bit silly to just place 2 form tags and that's it.` Lol, comment of the day :)

Comment: have you tried doing `'required': 'required'` in your function getExerciseTitle();

Comment: No I haven't, I'll give it a try. i'm glad I received the comment of the day award too. Thank you. EDIT: I just gave it a try, didn't work either.

Comment: @FllnAngl the `required` attribute is a boolean: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: @Macro Man well yes it is, but sometimes when sending an input like this. booleans aren't read correctly. cause it nearly looks like a json string to me, and json doesn't allow any code. just strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `submit` event is not firing. You're calling your `save` method on a button click. In your HTML, change the submit button type to "submit".

Before:

`<button type='button' id='saveBtn' class='btn btn-info fa fa-download fa-2x saveBtn' required name="submit" onclick="saveExerciseAjaxCall()"></button>`

After:

`<button type='submit' id='saveBtn' class='btn btn-info fa fa-download fa-2x saveBtn' required name="submit" onclick="saveExerciseAjaxCall()"></button>`

Then, if you want to submit the form without actually `POST`ing the data, you could do something like this in your JS:

```
$("#my_form").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: but if I do so, it will refresh the page. from what I have seen and heard u could do something with preventdefault();? but I guess that should also be implemented in my ajax call ? I did it and it worked. Thank you VERY much. I realy appreciate the effort

Comment: No problem. You beat me to that, but I did update my answer to include the part about `preventDefault`. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much sir, my grattitude towards you is immeasurable.